# How to uppercase first letter of the first word in each sentence using shell script?

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting and I am trying to capitalize each first letter of the first word in each sentence from a txt file called input.txt and I want this input file to be a argument of the shell script

```
 ./script.sh input.txt
```

sample input file:

```
i am Andrew. you are Jhon. here we are, forever.
```

result file:

```
I am Andrew. You are Jhon. Here we are, forever.
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could use sed for that

```
text = 'i am Andrew. you are Jhon. here we are, forever.'
echo $text | sed -E 's/(^[a-z]|\. [a-z])/\U&\E/g'
```

That script capitalizes whatever letter that comes after the start of the line or that comes after a `.`. Is this enough for your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use sed with a regex to look for the first sentence and any letter that comes after a period after that.  Apply the regex globally.

If there are headers in the text file, then it gets a little trickier unless you have a way of delimiting the headers.

```
man sed
```

Comment: I don't think this is an answer

Comment: Strictly speaking there wasn't a question.  I guessed that the question was "what approach should I take to solve this problem?".  This is a question-and-answer site, not an implement-other-people's-requirements site.